# Codeigniter achor producing dodgy link in email inbox.. what could the problem be?

Tags: php, mysql, html, email, codeigniter

My application is emailing out fine but the email I receive displays incorrectly. Rather than have text and a simple "click here to activate" link it doesn't. it shows this instead:

```
Hi user1, please click the following link to activate your account <a
href="http://mysite.com/activation/fzyZuyxVAzZS2koVg5UFjfVjlcLNcrzp">ssss</a>
```

Here is the code from my model that sends email to user when they request activation email.

```
   $this->load->library('email');
    $this->email->from('myemaill@gmail.com', 'my site');
    $this->email->to($result[0]->email);
    $this->email->subject('my site - Activate your account');
    $this->email->message('Hi ' . $result[0]->first_name . ', please click the following link to activate your account ' . anchor('http://mysite.com/activation/' . $new_activation_code, 'click here to activate'));
    $this->email->send();
```

Also the mail always ends up in my spam folder.

Comment: are you sending proper headers with the email? this can sometimes cause emails to be flagged as spam. the `from` should match the sending domain (generally)

Comment: I remember at one stage it was working fine. Could it be because I move half of the email code into a config file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The email format is plain text at the moment, you need to convert it to HTML via this option of the email library:

```
$config['mailtype'] = 'html';
$this->email->initialize($config);
```

[See Docs for more info](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/email.html)

Comment: This is set in my email.php config file. e.g. $config['mailtype']='html';

Comment: @Psychonetics: Hmm that is strange, try doing it from code too just in case like I have posted in my answer and then see if it works. Also try writing link yourself not with `anchor` method, it might be converting html to html entities.

Comment: Just commented out the one in config and tried it in my model and I get an error Call to undefined method CI_Email::mailtype()

Comment: @Psychonetics: I have updated the code, please check. Also it is good practice to put emailing code in controller :)